# operator '^': all operands must have the same enumeration type using FileInfo

Tags: c++-cli

I am using listbox for something and i am having troubles trying to scan the files

Here is the code:

```
private: System::Void simpleButton20_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->scan->Items->Clear();
    try {
        DirectoryInfo^ info = gcnew DirectoryInfo(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::UserProfile) + "\AppData\Roaming\skypedir\recievedfiles");
        //FileInfo^ info2 = gcnew FileInfo(SearchOption::AllDirectories);
        FileInfo^ info2 = gcnew FileInfo(info->GetFiles^("*jar*", SearchOption::AllDirectories));
        this->scan->Items->Add(info2->FullName);
    }
    catch(Exception^ Exe){
        MessageBox::Show(Exe->ToString());
    }
}
```

I recieve the error *"operator '^': all operands must have the same enumeration type"* everytime.

Comment: The ^ hat is appropriate on variable and parameter declarations, exact same idea as using * or & in a native C++ program.  It declares a pointer type, one that the garbage collector can find back.  It makes no sense on methods.

Answer (score 1):

The error you received is because of the operator '^' you typed after GetFiles. You don't need it.
But it will not solve your problem. Because, DirectoryInfo::GetFiles returns an array of FileInfo's. So, you cannot create a FileInfo object using GetFiles. You should do like following;

```
DirectoryInfo^ info = gcnew DirectoryInfo(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::UserProfile) + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\skypedir\\recievedfiles");
array<FileInfo^>^ fileInfoArray = info->GetFiles("*jar*", SearchOption::AllDirectories);
for each(FileInfo^ info2 in fileInfoArray)
{
   this->scan->Items->Add(info2->FullName);
}
```